# Wrong Google Drive Account

Tags: google, trello, google-drive

I have the wrong Google Drive account linked to my Trello; how do I correct this?

The email address I use to login is the correct email for Google Drive, but the files are not showing when I want to attach them—it shows me the files from a previous Google account.

Answer (score 1):

- Sign out of Google Drive from the incorrect Google Account.
- Attach a file from Google Drive and login to your Google Account to re-authorize Trello's access to your Google Drive.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can revoke access to Drive (or other Google services) at https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions

After this, you can link to a new account.